# Canvas image is not displaying in site

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, magento

We want to add some canvas background to the page as [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/apple/iphone-se/custom-iphone-se-cases/slim).

what we need is in site, it should display like below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgNw7.png)

we are using below code , but its displaying blank.

```
<div class="canvas-container" style="width: 300px; height: 500px; position: relative; -webkit-user-select: none;">
<canvas id="case_canvas" width="300" height="500" class="lower-canvas" style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 500px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
<canvas class="upper-canvas " width="300" height="500" style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 500px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: why was this tagged as javascript/php/magento when there's no relevant code?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i thought requires js code also , please help me with this.

Comment: If this is a magento issue, I can't be of help with this. If something comes up blank, then you may have syntax errors. Check your HTML source and do a var_dump also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can we use the same code that used in this [link](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/apple/iphone-se/custom-iphone-se-cases/slim)

Comment: I don't know and if there's any php being used in there and is the root of the problem, then there isn't much that can be done without knowing what the (php) source code is.

Comment: is it possible to implement such kind of feature only with javascript & html @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possibilities:

1st define a css background (I'm quite sure it's not the solution you're looking for but maybe this is an alternative to js)

```
.canvas-container {
   background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgNw7.png") no-repeat fixed center;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pmeb1uhm/

2nd draw the image on the canvas using js

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  //draw after loading
  canvas = document.getElementById('case_canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
}

img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgNw7.png";
//^^ this will start loading the image
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pmeb1uhm/1/

Comment: Thanks, i got something now [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/golden-waves-marble-texture-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html)

for different different models and brands if we select [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/select-mobile-tablet-case-model), we need to display difeerent different kind of canvas image as like

 [link1](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/letv/le1s-eco/custom-letv-le-1s-eco-cases/slim)  , 

 [link2](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/apple/iphone-se/custom-iphone-se-cases/slim) .

Comment: i am shocked how they are dislayinjg like that canvas backgrounds for different dropdown options, is that possible ?

Comment: We are using below code before . we can upload image here

[jsfiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/bwdzha94/)

after i merge your and my code , now i cant able to upload image

[jsfiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/r22oka49/) , please help me

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. You should definitively use a server for uploads.. what you currently do is referencing a local image and print it to the canvas.

Comment: sorry to inform  i didt needed this kind of solution, its my fault that i didt asked question correctly. if we check [link](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/apple/iphone-se/custom-iphone-se-cases/slim) & save the image to local computer or system , you can see image is not opening in local system.

in your answer, you mentioned url of image & gave the answer. thats fine, but when we upload new image, its not overlappig on the exisiting image.

please check I informed my requirements in details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698382/overlap-image2-on-image1)